# checkbox cookie and remembering to show hidden area

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox, show-hide

I have a form with check boxes. When you click the checkbox it displays a hidden label tag.

This is the JavaScript that I use:

```
$(".inline_collection :checkbox").click(function () {
    var hiddenVar = ".area" + this.value;
    if (this.checked) $(hiddenVar).show();
    else $(hiddenVar).hide();
});
```

and this is how the hidden section is coded into the body:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="show_hide" value="1a" id="1a" name="1a"></input>
<div class="area1a hidden">
    <label for="output">Step Completed! <img src="img/redCheck.png" /></label>
</div>
```

---

now, I use the following JavaScript along with jquery.cookie to create a cookie for the checkbox and repopulate it when the page is visited again:

```
$(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
});

$.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 365, path: '/' })
});

function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
        Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
        });
    }
}   

$.cookie.json = true;
repopulateCheckboxes();
```

---

Unfortunately the way it is now the checkboxes get repopulated but the hidden area is once again hidden on page reload. Right now I have my cookie code before my checkbox show/hide function. I've tried `.on(function` validate, `onChange`, on loads but I can't seem to get the hidden area to show itself when the checkboxes repopulate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing the labels is that the "click" and "change" events all only fire on user input. i.e. when some one clicks the checkbox.

These events do not get fired when the state is changed by javascript.

I put together a pretty hacky quick update of your code which now updates the checkbox label in a function and then calls this function both if the value is changed by cookie or on click.

A warning, I haven't actually tested this so there could be syntax issues but it's the concepts that really matter anyway.

```
$(".inline_collection :checkbox").click(function () {
    UpdateCheckboxLabel(this);
});

$(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });

    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 365, path: '/' })
});

function repopulateCheckboxes(){
var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
        Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked).each(function(){
                UpdateCheckboxLabel(this);
            });
        });
    }
}

function UpdateCheckboxLabel(t){
    var hiddenVar = ".area" + t.value;
    if (t.checked) $(hiddenVar).show();
    else $(hiddenVar).hide();
}

$.cookie.json = true;
repopulateCheckboxes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value in script will not trigger the events you've setup. To fix the initial setting of visibility, and not make any other changes to your code:

```
function repopulateCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
        Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            var jMatchingCheckbox = $(":checkbox[id='"+element+"']");
            if (jMatchingCheckbox) {
                jMatchingCheckbox.prop('checked', checked);
                $(".area" + jMatchingCheckbox.attr('id')).toggle(checked);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

An alternative to setting the visibility in javascript would be to use css selectors.

```
<style>
    .inline_collection input[type="checkbox"].show_hide:checked 
        ~ .show_only_when_checked 
    {
        display: block; 
    } 

    .inline_collection .show_only_when_checked 
    {
        display: none; 
    } 
</style>
<html>
    <span class="inline_collection">
        <input type="checkbox" class="show_hide" value="1a" id="1a" name="1a" />
        <div class="show_only_when_checked" data-checkbox-id="1a">
            <label for="output">Step Completed! <img src="img/redCheck.png" /></label>
        </div>
    </span>
</html>
```

A simple JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qnLKn/